# Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, socketrocket

I'm trying to connect between the client(iOS app) and the server(Node.js) with using SocketRocket and ws like this below.

iOS(SocketRocket):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"ws://localhost:8080"];
SRWebSocket *_socket = [SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
_socket.delegate = self;
[_socket open];

/* SRWebSocketDelegate */
-(void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket*)webSocket{
    [webSocket send:@"something"];
}
-(void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket*)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveMessage: %@",[message description]);
}
-(void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket*)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"the Error: %@",error);
}
```

Node.js(ws):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    host:'localhost',
    port:8080
});
wss.on('connection',function(ws){
    ws.on('message',function(message){
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        ws.send(message);
    });
});
```

Then, I got the message this below:

```
the error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"
```

I've searched to solve this, but I couldn't find the exactly solution for this.
How do I solve this??

Comment: Hi user3278637,I am facing same problem, Could you tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to the wi-fi network on your iPhone. Maybe solved that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `localhost` to your actual ip address like `10.28.8.146` can solve your problem.